# C++ Can't compare dereferenced char pointer to char

Tags: c++, string, xcode6

I have an input string, and I want to find how many spaces are there in the string.

Here's my code

```
// input string
std::string str = "abc d e f";

// convert string to cstring
char* cstr = new char[str.length()+1];
std::strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());

// iterate through the cstring and count how many spaces are there
int num_of_spaces = 0;
char* ptr = cstr;

while (ptr) {
    if (*ptr == ' ') {
        ++num_of_spaces;
    }
    ++ptr;
}
```

However, I got an error message on the `if (*ptr == ' ')` line that says: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address=0x100200000)`

Isn't `*ptr` a char type value because `ptr` is a `char*` pointer and I dereferenced it to `*ptr`. If so, why the comparison is not valid?

Comment: Why would you copy your nice safe `string` into dangerous raw memory?

Comment: ^--that.  Also, your loop says `while (ptr)`, equivalent to `while (ptr != NULL)`.  You are incrementing the pointer in your loop.  When do you think `ptr` will become NULL?

Comment: I think you want to be checking what `ptr` points to to find the end of the string: `while(ptr)` should be `while(*ptr)` no?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I could have iterated through the string and compare it to ' ' instead, but I was just learning char pointer. I would like to know how if I could do it with pointer

Comment: @Heisenberg, Your time would be better spent learning how to use algorithms like `std::count` so you don't write loops to reinvent them, no matter what you're iterating over.

Comment: @HostileFork isn't `c.str()` will copy the entire string including the NULL '\0' ? Found it here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Comment: @Heisenberg There is a big difference between a null pointer, and a pointer that is pointing to a character that has a byte value of zero (with the perhaps misleading name 'null terminator').  You are just incrementing a pointer value indefinitely...until you dereference it and read memory you shouldn't.  Study the difference between `ptr` and `*ptr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want `while (ptr)`, you want `while (*ptr)`, that is, while the thing `ptr` points to isn't a zero character which marks the end of a C-style string.

Comment: Oh apparently the error came from the infinite loop. That solved all the problem, thanks!